# Using "‪ נשתנה הטבע ‬" to change a Talmudic rule

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, chazon-ish

“It is a rule in the Talmud that, though a child born seven months after conception is viable (בר קיימא), one born after eight months is not viable. (It was a common belief in ancient medicine, also found in Hippocrates, Aristotle, and Galen.) This belief has a number of halachic consequences, including the ruling that one may not violate the Shabbat for the sake of the health of an eight-month child. The Hazon Ish (Abraham Isaiah Karelitz, 1878-1953) issued a p'sak that, in our time, this rule did not apply. His justification for changing the Talmudic rule was " נשתנה הטבע ", (the natural order has changed)”

Can someone:

A. Cite me where in the Gemara it talks about this

B. Cite the psak of the Hazon Ish

Comment: Where is your quote from??

Comment: "where in the Gemara it talks about this" 8 month babies? or נשתנה הטבע?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Source in Gemara is [Shabbos 135:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14314&st=&pgnum=270)

> בן שבעה מחללים עליו את השבת ובן שמונה אין מחללים עליו את השבת, ספק בן
> שבעה ספק בן שמונה אין מחללים עליו את השבת, בן שמונה הרי הוא כאבן ואסור
> לטלטלו, אבל אמו שוחה עליו ומניקתו מפני הסכנה

Gemara says that a child born in the eighth month, one may not desecrate Shabbos for them.

[See here](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=29135)

[Chazon Ish יו"ד קנה, ד](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14334&st=&pgnum=376&hilite=)

> יש שטועין וסוברים דהנולד קודם ט' הוא נפל ומתיאשין הימנו ואינם זריזין
> ברפואתו, וזו טעות... וחייבים להשתדל ברפואתו... בימים הראשונים הי'
> מיעוט המצוי שנגמרו לז', ורובן לתשעה, אבל לא היו נגמרין לשמונה, ולפיכך
> אמרו האי בן שבעה הוא ואשתהי, וכמדומה דעכשיו נשתנה הטבע, וכפי בחינת
> הרופאים, אפשר שהוסיפו השתלמותם אחר ז' ונגמרו לח', והרי נשתנו הטבעים
> ללדת למקוטעין, כמ"ש הרמ"א

Chazon Ish says that the nature changed for those born at eight months, and one may desecrate Shabbos for them.